# Drools rule templates and the forall decision table construct

Tags: jboss, rules, drools

Currently trying to prove a database driven rule template that is using comma separated input paramaters. We are trying to reuse the forall decision table construct that does not appear to work with rule templates.

E.g.

```
<code>
template header
myCommaSeparated

package test.package;

template "Test Rule"
rule "@{row.rowNumber}"

    when
        forall(||){@{myCommaSeparated}}
    then        

end
end template   
</code>
```

This does not work. According to the docs rule templates should be able to do everything a decision table can do ??

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the status of a similar (the same?) question on the drools-user mailing list: http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-Rule-Templates-comma-separated-data-td3091621.html